# Green function of first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I want to find the Green's function (kernel) of the following problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
(a(x)u')'=f, \text{ in } (-1, 1)\\[4pt]
u(1)=u(-1)=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where, $a(x)\in L^{\infty}(-1, 1)$ and $f\in L^{\infty}(-1, 1)$. I take the homogenuous part with $f=0$ and develop the problem as, setting $g(x, s)$ be the Green function,
\begin{equation}
g''(x, s)+\dfrac{a'(x)}{a(x)}g'(x, s)=0,
\end{equation}
Solving this problem, I obtain 
$$
g'(x, s)=\dfrac{c_1}{a(x)}
$$
and consequently
$$
g(x, s)=\int \dfrac{c_1}{a(x)}\,dx +c_2.
$$
Is this correct? and if this is correct I get $c_1=c_2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising that you get $0$ when solving a homogeneous ODE with homogeneous boundary conditions.

Green's function $g(x,s)$ for a differential operator $L$ satisfies the equation $Lg(x,s) = \delta_s$, where $\delta_s$ is the Dirac delta at $x=s$. In order for $(au')'$ to be $\delta_s$, you need $au'$ to have a jump discontnuity of size $1$ at $x=s$. This means $u'$ should have jump discontinuity of size $1/a(s)$. So, instead of 
$$g'(x, s)=\dfrac{c_1}{a(x)} $$
you need
$$g'(x, s)=\dfrac{c_1 + H(x-s)}{a(x)}$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function. This gives
$$g(x, s)=\int_{-1}^x \dfrac{c_1 + H(t-s)}{a(t)}\,dt$$
where the constant $c_1$ is determined from the condition $g(1,s)=0$: that is, 
$$c_1\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{a(t)}\,dt + \int_s^1 \frac{1}{a(t)}\,dt = 0$$